# Mongoose updating object field properties in document

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am having a problem where an object in my document would not get updated. In my `Class` Model, there's a field called **sentiment** of type `Object` as the following:

```
sentiment: {
  terrible: 0,
  bad: 0,
  okay: 0,
  good: 0,
  fantastic: 0
}
```

The way I implemented `sentiment` in my model is as following:

```
sentiment: Object
```

To update the property, I am passing an object with the field `sentiment` that contains the actual sentiment:

```
{ sentiment: 'good' } // this is what req.body contains
```

I am doing this:

```
const classFound = await Class.findById(req.params.classId);
if (classFound) {
  classFound.sentiment[req.body.sentiment] += 1;
  await classFound.save();
}
```

But when I retrieve the class, the `sentiment` object remains unchanged. I am not sure where the bug is because when I log out `classFound` after `save()`, I get the updated **sentiment** object.

**EDIT**

```
Class.js // class Schema
const classSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  abbr: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  sentiment: {
    terrible: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    bad: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    okay: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    good: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    fantastic: { type: Number, default: 0 }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const update = (query, body) => {
    return new Promise((resove, reject) => {
        Class.update(query, body, (err, data) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            return resove(data);
        });
    });
}

const classFound = await Class.findOne({
    _id: req.params.classId
}).exec(); // exec returns promise
if (classFound) {
    const sentiment = req.body.sentiment;
    classFound.sentiment[sentiment] = classFound.sentiment[sentiment] ? classFound.sentiment[sentiment] + 1 : 1;
    const query = {
        _id: req.params.classId
    };
    const body = {
        $set: {
            sentiment: classFound.sentiment
        }
    };
    await update(query, body);
}
```

Comment: I tried to use set previously, but it didn't work for me

Comment: can you add sample data of Class schema?

Comment: Added it in the post

Comment: sentiment: {
  terrible: 0,
  bad: 0,
  okay: 0,
  good: 0,
  fantastic: 0
} It's there right? I think `classFound.sentiment[req.body.sentiment]` not found

Comment: I have logged `classFound.sentiment[req.body.sentiment]` in my terminal and it displays the value `0` that is associated but it does not update it correctly.

Comment: what's API route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165569/discussion-between-narulakeshav-and-rahul-sharma).